# Primefaces session expired press Command Button not redirect

Tags: session, jsf-2, primefaces

I'm using PrimeFaces 5.1. In my If user working in browser at a time same username login another browser at a time invalidate previous session. Now faces problem in invalidate is work fine. Previous session user perform dropdown or check click redirect home page is work find. But CommandButton or CommandLink press it will not redirect to home page.
When I set ajax="false" commandButton only redirect otherwise set ajax=true or not set ajax=false commandButton not redirect.

Comment: Search the internet for 'jsf ajax exceptionhandler' (hint: PrimeFaces has one, as does omnifaces)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Uncaught Exception Handling in JSF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16675663/uncaught-exception-handling-in-jsf)